# can imacro create dynamic folder if not present?

Tags: imacros

I want to create the folder if it is not present in downloads folder while taking the screenshot and save in that folder respective.

I tries this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120
SET !DATASOURCE W:\test.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
SET VAR1 {{!COL1}}
SCREENSHOT TYPE=Page FOLDER=C:\Users\kinjal.gada\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}} FILE={{VAR1}}
```

but this gives an error

```
RuntimeError: Path C:\Users\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\+23012015 does not exists, line 14 (Error code: -932)
```

Is there any way to make the folder at runtime?

thanks

Comment: You can't use special characters like + etc. Try to create folder without i.